# what is the efficient way to reuse async function from different file location in nodejs 4.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

This is a working sample code which call async function from different location and reuse the result with some calculation. In this case I used "Promise" two times.

- first Promise: get async value from different file location.
- second Promise: wait until get result from the first Promise to reuse in main.js file.

What is the efficient way to do this operation with using 'callbacks' or 'promises' ?

---

My code:

in `./folder1/sub.js`

```
function func(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var value = 5; // resolve value
        setTimeout(function(){
            value += 5;
            err = false;
            if(err) return reject(err);
            resolve(value);
        },3000);
    });
}

module.exports={
    getValue: func
}
```

in `./main.js`

```
var sub = require('./folder1/sub');

function nextfunc(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        sub.getValue().then(function(val){
            console.log(val);
            // do some calculations
            val+=5;
            err = false;
            if(err) return reject(err);
            resolve(val);
        });
    });
}

var last = nextfunc();
last.then(function(last){
    console.log('last -', last);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

Funtion

```
module.exports = function func(value){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var value = 5; // remove value from here
      .....
```

Main

```
var sub = require('./folder1/sub');

function nextfunc(){

         return sub.getValue(initialValue).then(function(val){
           return sub.getValue(val)
        });

}

var last = nextfunc();
last.then(function(last){
    console.log('last -', last);
});
```